# make: *** No rule to make target 'distclean'. Stop

Tags: makefile, compilation, vlc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, configure

I'm trying to compile VLC, I already did ./configure, exported PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR and when I try to configure.sh, I get:

```
64-pc-linux-gnu
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-strip... x86_64-linux-gnu-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
```

When I run "make distclean", I get the

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'distclean'.  Stop.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

This error is generated when the build is out of source directory and the source directory is configured, e.g. there exists `config.status` file.

```
  # test to see if srcdir already configured
  if test -f $srcdir/config.status; then
    as_fn_error $? "source directory already configured; run \"make distclean\" there first" "$LINENO" 5
  fi
```

Either run `make distclean` in source directory or remove `config.status` from there.